# Laravel offset and limit on with()?

Tags: php, laravel, web, orm

When I do this, it doesn't do what I expect - get the "paginated" result of the related comments per post. Below, it only returns the comments of the first post.

```php
   Post::with(['comments' => function($query) {
       $query->offset(0)->limit(10);
   }])->get()
```

Result:

```
  [
       {
          ...
          "comments" : [
             [Comment], [Comment], [Comment]  # <-- Only this post has comments.
          ]
       }, 

       {
           ...
           "comments" : [

           ]               # <-- Other posts do not have comments. =(
       }
  ]
```

I aim to have each array item above to have a max of 10 comments in "paginated" manner using offset and limit on with().

Is it possible to do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

`offset(0)` can be omitted

```
Album::with(['images' => function ($query) {
    $query->limit(10);
}])->get();
```

if you need to have **ONLY** posts that have comments only you can do it like this with **whereHas**:

```
    Post::whereHas('comments', function($query) {
       $query->whereNotNull('image')->limit(10);
   }])->get()
```

Comment: The second record onward have empty 'images' array when I do something similar to your answer. Thank you for the answer, though!

Comment: Answer was updated, please check it.  If the answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted/upvote for benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Get **Posts** with **Comments** - limit number of comments to 10

```php
Post::with(['comments' => fn($query => $query->limit(10)])->get();
```

Only get those **Posts** which have at least 1 **Comment** and limit the maximum number of comments to 10

```php
Post::with(['comments' => fn($query) => $query->limit(10)])
    ->has('comments')
    ->get();
```

Only get those **Posts** which have at least 5 **Comments** and limit the maximum number of comments to 10

```php
Post::with(['comments' => fn($query) => $query->limit(10)])
    ->has('comments', '>=', 5)
    ->get();
```

Get only those **Posts** which have at least 5, **Comments** containing "lara", and limit the maximum number of comments to 10

```php
Post::with(['comments' => fn($query) => $query->limit(10)])
    ->whereHas(
        //Relation
        'comments', 

        //Constrain to filter comments - only comments which contain "lara"
        fn($query) => $query->where('content', 'like', 'lara%'), 
       
        //Comparison Operator indicates minimum
        '>=', 

        //Along with operator says minimum of 5 records which fulfil the constrain
        5
    )
    ->get();
```